# How to keep responsive layout in WebView Android app?

Tags: android, webview

I have created an Android app using `WebView`. This app shows the content of a website. There are many internal links and external links (with a 301 redirect). Internal links are correct, but when I tap on external links, I see a fullscreen desktop layout instead of the responsive version of the page and it looks very bad.

How do I edit the following code in order to always get the responsive layout to fit the screen?

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
            // hide loading image
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(description).setPositiveButton(getText(R.string.ok), null).setTitle("onReceivedError");
            builder.show();
        }

    });

    // load url (if connection available
    if (isInternetConnected(this)) {
        String URL = "http://www.example.com/";
        webView.loadUrl(URL);
    }else{
       // showAlertDialog(this, "No Internet Connection",
      //          "You don't have internet connection.", false);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                .setMessage("You don't have internet connection.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // whatever...
                        finish(); //Close current activity
                        startActivity(getIntent()); //Restart it

                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are testing on a `tablet` and amazon website looks similar to `desktop version` from a tablet, while it becomes responsive when browsed from a `phone`.

Please try from a `standard phone` and you'll see that its mobile version of the site :)

Please let me know in case your problem isn't solved.

Thanks

Sanskar